# Amazon Merchant Web Services InputDataError on SubmitFeed

Tags: php, xml, curl, amazon-mws

I'm using Amazon MWS API and am trying to update my inventory stock levels using SubmitFeed, however, it always returns InputDataError, with no further information. I have contacted Amazon for more details on why I would receive this error and they have informed me that it's a parsing error and sent me the most up to date XSD's to check my XML against, but I can't see any issues with the XML. The XML I'm sending is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
  <Header>
   <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
   <MerchantIdentifier>MY_MERCHANT_TOKEN</MerchantIdentifier>
  </Header>
  <MessageType>Inventory</MessageType>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Inventory>
      <SKU>2360</SKU>
      <Quantity>3</Quantity>
      <FullfillmentLatency>1</FullfillmentLatency>
    </Inventory>
  </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

I'm using phps cURL to build the post to send the request as follows:

```
function submitFeed($xmldata, $request)
{
  $request['Signature']=$this->_signParameters($request,$this->_awsSecretAccessKey);
  $url_with_fields="https://mws.amazonservices.co.uk?".$this->_getParametersAsString($request);
  $md5=md5($xmldata);

  $ch = curl_init();               
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
      'Content-Type: text/xml',                        
      'Content-MD5: '. $md5,
      'Transfer-Encoding: chunked'
  ));

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url_with_fields);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT , 443);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmldata); 


  //execute post
  $result = curl_exec($ch);


  print_r($result);

  //close connection
  curl_close($ch);
}
```

I'm not that experienced with cUrl and am wondering if there is something I'm missing here?

Comment: OK, I've now used the Amazon SubmitFeedSample in their PHP package and the feed has submitted fine with the XML above. So that is not the issue, I have a feeling that it's something to do with the way the requested is being constructed in my own code. I'll see what I can figure out from the Amazon package and if I come up with a solution will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `<FullfillmentLatency>1</FullfillmentLatency>` with `<FulfillmentLatency>1</FulfillmentLatency>`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. Unfortunately, I am still receiving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

did you check the xml using a scratchpad. I am sure there is a issue with xml. 
The inventory XSD has a sequence follow it to create the xml and test in scrathpad.